Implement a derived attribute in Rails 7
I am trying to implement a derived field in Rails 7. I have a Tag model. A tag has a prefix, a loop number, and an optional suffix. (Yes, I'm an instrument engineer :-) I keep these attributes separately in the database, because it is required to sort and search on them individually, but most of the time the tag is referenced and displayed as the combination of these fields. I defined an attribute accessor, and a setter function in private, to join the fields, and I set the after_find helper to trigger the setter. But they don't seem to work. In the console, Tag.first.full_tag results in nil, and nothing is displayed in views.
I would have thought this requirement is relatively common, but haven't found anything useful in my searches. Of course, I could probably persist the derived attribute into the database, but that would contravene the basic rule of "one source of information". I would greatly appreciate if someone can point out where I am going wrong.
# tag.rb:
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :discipline, foreign_key: :discipline, primary_key: :code

  attr_reader :full_tag
  after_find :set_full_tag

...

 private

    def set_full_tag
      full_tag = prefix + "-" + loop.to_s.rjust(4, '0')
      if !suffix.empty?
        full_tag += "." + suffix
      end
    end
end


you need to use an instance variable @full_tag.

This is a pretty good use case for a generated column if your database supports it. The advantage being that you can query by the full tag without having to deconstruct it and query X number of columns.

Also beware that you're shadowing the Kernel#loop method from the Ruby core which creates a real WOT? moment when reading the code. Use another name.

Thanks @max I wasn't aware of that. Is there a master list of attribute names to avoid? I will revise loop, can I use "number"?

Thanks @Alex, can you make that an answer?

@FBtLL there are few but none that are really that complete or up to date. loop usually isn't on the list as it's a method and not a keyword.

@max I found that thread and copied all the lists into a file for reference, it may be useful. And I added a section for additions like 'loop' that pop out. This probably should be in official documentation somewhere. I'm sure people would find it useful.

So, let's build an example here:
Proposed Code:
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  # attr_accessor for the derived full_tag
  attr_accessor :full_tag
  
  # Set the full_tag after finding the record
  after_find :set_full_tag

  private

  def set_full_tag
    # Set the full_tag on the instance using self.full_tag
    self.full_tag = "#{prefix}-#{self.loop_number.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}"
    
    # Add suffix if it's present
    self.full_tag += ".#{suffix}" if suffix.present?
  end
end

The main issue (as I see it) with the original code is that it does not correctly set the full_tag value. To fix this, we first replace attr_reader with attr_accessor. Why? attr_reader only lets you read the value, while attr_accessor lets you both read and write it. As I understand it, you want to change the full_tag value after finding the record.
Next, full_tag = ... creates a temporary variable, which doesn't store the combined tag in the model. We can use self.full_tag = ..., to tell Rails to use the setter method generated by attr_accessor, so that the full_tag value is properly updated and saved in the object.
I hope this points you in the right direction.
Test Framework:
rails new tag_proj
cd tag_proj
rails generate model Tag prefix:string loop_number:integer suffix:string
rails db:migrate

echo "
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :full_tag
  after_find :set_full_tag

  private

  def set_full_tag
    self.full_tag = \"#{prefix}-#{self.loop_number.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}\"
    self.full_tag += \".#{suffix}\" if suffix.present?
  end
end
" > app/models/tag.rb

echo "
Tag.create(prefix: 'XX', loop_number: 123, suffix: 'A')
Tag.create(prefix: 'YY', loop_number: 45, suffix: 'B')
Tag.create(prefix: 'ZZ', loop_number: 67, suffix: nil)
" >> db/seeds.rb

rails db:seed

echo "
# lib/tasks/tag_full_tag.rake
namespace :tag do
  task full_tag: :environment do
    puts Tag.first.full_tag   
    puts Tag.second.full_tag
    puts Tag.third.full_tag
  end
end
" > lib/tasks/tag_full_tag.rake

rake tag:full_tag

Output
> rake tag:full_tag
XX-0123.A
YY-0045.B
ZZ-0067


You might not even need it.
Ruby doesn't actually even have "real" attributes. It just has methods:
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  def full_tag
    "#{prefix}-#{loop.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}".tap do |str|
      str.concat(".#{suffix}") if suffix.present?
    end
  end
end

And instance variables which are just variables that can be assigned whilly nilly and are scoped to an object (a class/module or an instance of a class):
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  def full_tag
    @full_tag ||= "#{prefix}-#{loop.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}".tap do |str|
      str.concat(".#{suffix}") if suffix.present?
    end
  end
end

The pattern used here is known as memoization and will avoid creating a new string every time the method is called.
Ruby does however provide the basic building blocks to create any "attribute system" that you want.
Rails has the ActiveModel::Attributes API which is generic and can be mixed into any class and ActiveRecord::Attributes which assumes the object is backed by a database table. If you reallyy want is an attribute that behaves like the attributes that Rails creates from your schema you can use the attributes API:
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :full_tag, :string
  after_find :set_full_tag
  after_initialize :set_full_tag

  def set_full_tag
    self.full_tag = "#{prefix}-#{loop.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}".tap do |str|
      str.concat("." + suffix) if suffix.present?
    end
  end
end

The difference here is this will be included when serializing the model or if you for example call Tag.new(...).attributes as the metadata about the attribute is stored in a separate class instance variable.

Thanks for your assistance. Assuming you meant full_tag not full_name, this also works. I'm not at high enough level to understand all the nuances. I agree with your earlier comment that a database generated column would be the ideal solution, so I'm studying up on that.

Oops, yes I meant full_tag.

@FBtLL And PS the mistake you where doing in you question is a pretty common one. In Ruby you can call methods with an implicit recipient (without self). But if you want to call a setter method you always need to explicitly call them on self self.full_tag = ...  otherwise Ruby just thinks you want to assign a local variable.

Thanks again@max, coming back to this after some other issues. After looking into the database generated column, I didn't get very far. I found only one article that showed an example using the virtual key word for migrations (https://www.mintbit.com/blog/creating-virtual-columns-in-rails-7-a-step-by-step-guide), but that doesn't work for me. The migration runs but the schema has this message: # Could not dump table "test_virtuals" because of following StandardError
Unknown type 'virtual' for column 'full_name'. Possibly I need a later rails version.

@FBtLL please ask it as a separate question.

Good idea
